# getting a blob from the stream

Tags: javascript, meteor, pdfkit

This Meteor server code tries to create a pdf in order to attach it to an email. It  make the pdf Ok but when puting it into a blob, it returns this error:

> TypeError: Blob is not a function

```
"use strict";
let PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
let blobStream = require('blob-stream');

'make': function () {
    let doc = new PDFDocument(metaData);  // readable Node streams
    let stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());
    doc.fontSize('14')
      .text('some text')
      .end();
    stream.on('finish', function (blob) {
      return stream.toBlob(blob); //<=== error line
    });
  },
```

Comment: from where does `metaData` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Documentation](http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html) , `stream.toBlob()` is expecting type of output for blob, i.e. `application/text`, `application/pdf`.

Can you please try below peice of code,

```
stream.on('finish', function () {
 //get a blob you can do whatever you like with
 blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf');
 return blob;
});
```

Kindly go through the Documentation. It says below,

> PDFDocument instances are readable Node streams. They don't get saved anywhere automatically, but you can call the `pipe` method to send the output of the PDF document to another writable Node stream as it is being written. When you're done with your document, call the `end` method to finalize it. Here is an example showing how to pipe to a file or an HTTP response.

```
doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.pdf') # write to PDF
doc.pipe res                                       # HTTP response

# add stuff to PDF here using methods described below...

# finalize the PDF and end the stream
doc.end();
```

Comment: I am getting the same error still. I changed the line to `let blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf');`

Comment: Can you produce the stack trace within your question? So that everyone could see what is wrong?

Comment: updated my answer with more detail. You need to follow proper guidelines from Documentation. You need to reconfirm your `doc.pipe` code. Refer above for more.

Comment: I am having hard time following the coffee-script syntax. I need to not save this to a local file. any way of doing it?

Comment: @Fred: Did my answer was exactly enough to solve issue or you did something else to achieve it? If Yes then can you update my answer as edit request ? The other people must know how exactly you achieved it :)